# Issue on Applying CSS Specific Rules Only On Safari

Tags: css

Can you please let me know how I can apply a specific rule like

```
.btn{width:25%;}
```

only on Safari? right now I have a rule .btn{width:23%;} which is working fine in all browsers but not in safari (my app btns looks smaller at safari). 
I already saw some [Browser Specific Hacks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/) but they were very confusing for me.

Thanks

Comment: Does everything look smaller in safari? If so your zoom level may be less than 100% - I'm pretty sure Chrome and Safari both use the webkit engine so it shouldn'tappear to much different

Comment: Thanks Alex but no just buttons look different! everything else are same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* Safari Specific CSS */

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 

         ::i-block-chrome,.btn{
           width:25%;
           }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

So looking at the Browser Specific hacks URL that you posted. I am not sure what was so confusing about it...

```
html[xmlns*=""]:root .btn{
    width:25%;
}
```

This should work